# How would one go about solving these types of problems?

Tags: induction, trees, binary

I'm totally lost. All I know is it has to do with binary trees and may need to be solved using induction.

1. Show that every 2-tree with $n$ internal nodes has $n + 1$ external nodes.
2. Show that the external path length ($epl$) in a 2-tree with $m$ external nodes satisfies $epl \leq \frac{1}{2}(m^2 + m - 2)$. Conclude that $epl \leq \frac{1}{2}n(n + 3)$ for a 2-tree with $n$ internal nodes.

---

**Edit**

In response to answer 2:

I know that if there are n internal nodes, there are n + 1 external (or m external and m - 1 internal) and that a tree has the maximum external path length if each node has at most one internal child. Such a length is defined by $epl_{max} = \frac{1}{2}n(n + 3)$. How do you go from $epl_{max}$ to $\frac{1}{2}m(m - 1) + (m - 1)$? And if $epl = n + 2m$, wouldn't it be,

$n + 2m <= \frac{1}{2}(m^2 + m - 2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ans 1:**

For **$n=1$**, we have $0$ internal nodes and $1$ external node.

**Induction Hypothesis**: The 2-tree with $n-1$ internal nodes has $n$ external nodes.

Now, if you add $2$ nodes to one of the external node of a 2-tree with $n-1$ internal nodes, we get a 2-tree with $n$ internal nodes and the number of external nodes decreases by $1$ (since by adding $2$ nodes to an external node makes that (external) node an internal node in the new tree) and increases by 2 (since we are adding $2$ new nodes). This implies that the number of external nodes becomes $n-1+2 = n+1$.

**Ans 2**:

For a fixed number of external nodes, maximum $epl$ can be obtained when we make a tree which looks like this:

[image: Maximum EPL Graph]

Red - Internal Nodes

Green - External Nodes

$epl \leq epl_{max} = \frac{1}{2}m(m-1) + (m-1) = (m-1)(\frac{m}{2} +1) = \frac{1}{2}(m-1)(m+2) = \frac{1}{2}(m^2 + m - 2)$

$m$ external nodes means $m-1$ internal nodes.

$n = m-1$. Put $m=n+1$ to get the desired result.

Comment: please read the edit above

Comment: see the figure. $m$ = number of external nodes. $epl_{max}=$ sum of distance of each external node from root $= 1 + 2 + \dots + (m-1) + (m-1) = \frac{1}{2}m(m-1) + (m-1)$ (I used the formula for the sum of first (m-1) natural numbers ).  Now if you want to write the formula in terms of $n$, just substitute $m$ by $n+1$ in the formula (since you want the formula in terms of # of internal nodes ($= n$) and we know $n = m-1 \implies m = n-1$)

Comment: Now the case you were talking about $epl = n+2m$. If you know $epl = n+2m$ then, yes, $n + 2m  < \frac{1}{2}(m^2 + m -2)$. $n+2m = m-1 + 2m = 3m -1 < \frac{1}{2}(m^2 + m -2) \implies 6m - 2 < m^2 + m -2 \implies m^2 -5m >0 \implies m(m-5) > 0 \implies m>5$ (since $m>0$)

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, thank you!